# Google Pub/Sub set enable message retention on topic programatically

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

In google pub/sub, if topic created, we could set the retention policy

https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub

[image: list of topics]

by clicking, edit, edit topic, update

[image: updating retention policy]

is it possible to update this value programmatically?

I see that there is such configuration on subscription level https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/main/pubsub/subscription.go#L564
but not in the topic level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, message retention can be configured in the topic programmatically. In Go, you would set the [`RetentionDuration` in the `TopicConfig`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/134e37b184cb8fcec1c93a4cd53df3cf60280dc9/pubsub/topic.go#L224-L234) and pass that to `CreateTopicWithConfig` to do it at create time:

```
tc := TopicConfig{
    RetentionDuration = 168 * time.Hour
}
topic, err := c.CreateTopicWithConfig(context.Background(), "my-topic", tc)
```

To do it at update time, you set the property in the `TopicConfigToUpdate` and pass it to `Update`:

```
topic := client.Topic("my-topic")
topicConfig, err := topic.Update(ctx, pubsub.TopicConfigToUpdate{
  RetentionDuration = 168 * time.Hour
})
```